# Adding image to richtext box

Tags: c#, winforms

I would really appreciate it, if someone could please assist me with the following problem.

So I have already added the image to my resource file, what I want to know is how would you assign the image to button, and also after a user clicks on the button the image is pasted on a richtext box. I am using C# Windows.System.Forms for this. Please kindly assist me.

Thanks,
Harshita

Comment: can you post your progression so far?

Comment: there is also a Control called `PictureBox`.. this is the best to display images.

Comment: There is no nice way at all. The only one I know is to use the `Clipboard`. It results in valid `Rtf` but the result is still awkward, a bit like early Word versions.

Comment: easier to just use `WebBrowser` control instead

Answer (score 0):

If you have indeed assigned the `Image` to the `Button`'s `BackgroundImage`, maybe like this:

```
button1.BackgroundImage = 
                 (Bitmap)Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("ImageNameWithoutExtension");
```

then this will copy it to the `ClipBoard` and `Paste` it at the current `SelectionStart` of  a `RichTextBox` :

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = sender as Button;
    Clipboard.SetData("Bitmap", btn.BackgroundImage);
    richTextBox1.Paste();
}
```

It uses the sender parameter so you can use the same event for all your image buttons.